# I Ejaculated 15 before Fajr. Did ghusl. 10 minutes after Fajr I noticed a ejaculation stain on my leg. Is my fast valid still because I did ghusl

Tags: ramadan, ghusl, fajr

I Ejaculated 15 before Fajr. Did ghusl. 10 minutes after Fajr I noticed a ejaculation stain on my leg. Is my fast valid still because I did ghusl well as I thought but I wasn’t well. Is my fast valid?

Comment: Unless you are Ibadi the necessity of ghusl and validity of fast have no correlation.

Comment: I’m just a Muslim that follow the sun nah of prophet Muhammad swt. So does it invalidate my fast ?